# Comparative and "zu" sentence

Tags: comparative

I have encountered this sentence in Duden:

> Eher will ich sterben, als diesen Greis heiraten.

I thought it should have been like this:

> Eher will ich sterben, als diesen Greis **zu** heiraten.

Why wasn't it written like that?

Comment: It's a bit blown-up version of: Eher will ich sterben als heiraten, where you might not want to put a "zu" into it.

Comment: @mic But why not "Eher will ich sterben als zu heiraten"?

Comment: @ choXer - it would be as if saying;: Ich will zu heiraten, which is wrong.

Comment: @mic "Eher will ich angeln als laufen." I thought it would be "Eher will ich angeln als zu laufen", thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the the same ambiguity appears in English: "I would rather die than marry ..." vs. "I would rather die than to marry ...". Interchangeable to my ears.

Comment: The version with "zu" sounds strange to me. If it were "Eher will ich diesen Greis töten, als ihn zu heiraten", so "dieser Greis" is the subject of the first sentence as well, then including "zu" sounds better. Being a native, I don't know whether this is some grammar rule, but my guess is that you only include the "zu" when the two verbs being compared have the same subject.

Answer (score 2):

In a comparison „Eher x als y“ the phrase y *only* names the difference to x.

In your examples the infinitive „heiraten“ matches „sterben“, while „zu heiraten“ matches the whole predicate „sterben wollen“.

Assuming the lady does not want to die, these examples boil down to:

> Ich will diesen Greis nicht heiraten.

and

> Ich heirate diesen Greis nicht.

---

**Addendum**

Jann asked for an «example sentence where absence/presence of "zu" produces two distinct yet sensical meanings»:

> Ich lasse dich lieber schlafen als Trompete spielen.
>
> Ich lasse dich lieber schlafen als Trompete zu spielen.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Can you come up with an example sentence where absence/presence of "zu" produces two distinct yet sensical meanings?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. Should I also explain the differences of „als“ + simple phrase (including an infinitive) and „als“+clause (including an infinitive with „zu“)? That would be easy, but as a native speaker I cannot give reasons.

Answer (score 1):

IMO both are (kind of) possible grammatically, the version without "zu" makes more sense though.

If "will ich" is supposed to refer to both "sterben" and "heiraten", the version without "zu" is correct:

> Eher will ich sterben als diesen Greis heiraten.

The extended infinitive with "zu" is only needed if the two alternatives compared by "als" are the whole two sentences, including the verb. Let's look at this slightly different example:

> Eher sterbe ich, als diesen Greis zu heiraten.

Here it is clear that the comparison is between "ich sterbe" und "ich heirate diesen Greis", and that comparison needs "zu".

So if we understand

> Eher will ich sterben, als diesen Greis zu heiraten.

as a comparison between the alternatives "ich will sterben" and "ich heirate diesen Greis" (which I certainly don't want), then the "zu" is actually fine. Whether that makes sense semantically is a different question though - "sterben" is normally not seen as something desirable either, so the variant without "zu" does seem to make more sense.